# Determing if a NSString has all unique characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, unique

(For example, "assdf" and "aash"  would be considered false).

Comment: What do you mean 'unique characters'?  Both of those strings have at least one duplicate character, and they share characters with one another, too.

Comment: u wnat to check that ur string hase unique character ???

Comment: surely your examples are false? one has 2 ss and the other 2 a s. i'd downvote you only i've used up all my votes today... count yourself lucky.

Comment: sorry, i edit it, i mean they're false

Answer (score 5):

I think you stated the problem backwards, but to test if every character in an NSString is unique, I think the following should work. There may be some funny unicode edge cases that don't work, where identical glyphs show up as different code points.

```
@interface NSString(_uniqueChars)
-(BOOL) isEveryCharacterUnique;
@end

@implementation NSString(_uniqueChars)
-(BOOL) isEveryCharacterUnique
{
    NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:self.length];
    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.length; ++i )
    {
        unichar c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        [set addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:c]];
    }

    return (set.count == self.length);
}
@end
```

Comment: I was trying to do it with NSCharacterSet, too bad that it hasn't a count property. But nothing to do, +1 for a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also was trying   NSCharacterSet but no results. This could be another solution but +1 for a better one.

```
   - (BOOL) isUnique: (NSString *) aString{

        int len = (int)aString.length;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            NSString *tmp = [aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
            {
                if([[aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1)]isEqualToString: tmp])
                {
                    return NO;
                }
            }
        }
        return YES;
   }
```